Are there any special vacuum cases of quantum gravity theories like there is for the General Theory of Relativity?
General Relativity has Special Relativity as a special case of the general theory in vacuo. Do theories of quantum gravity have general and special cases for in vacuo limits as well, or is this not the appropriate way to think of quantum gravity? I would also be interested in answers to the question of should theories of quantum gravity have general and special theories, if they do not exist already.

Are you looking for something like this? https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9405057 -- Basically, in the low energy limit, quantum gravity should reduce to general relativity + small quantum corrections, and the small corrections are computable (or at least, can be parameterized) using effective field theory.
